# Array display without key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to display an array without key item. Just want to display array values without key.
Here is my sample code I tried

```
$myList = array(
        0 =>array(
                "product_id"=> 8085
            ),
         1 =>array(
                "product_id"=> 8087
            ),
          2 =>array(
                "product_id"=> 8086
            ),
           3 =>array(
                "product_id"=> 8042
            ),
        );


  $newList = array();
foreach($myList as $listItem) {
    $newList[] = $listItem['product_id'];
}
$a=array();
$a= array_values($newList);
print_r($a);
```

I want my array like this

```
$productIds = array(8085,8087,8086,8042);
```

Here is my sample code [link](https://eval.in/718887)

Comment: Do you want it look like this when you print it? Because your `look like this` part is an php code line!

Comment: If you print your array with `print_r()` it will always print the array keys. You might want to use `implode()` or some simple loop with `echo`.

Comment: `$newList` is already in that format. Dont understand whats wrong.

Comment: Else  `array(8085,8087,8086,8042);` is equal to `array(0=>8085,1=>8087,2=>8086,3=>8042);`

Comment: if you want an array _"I want my array like this"_ Then you will always have keys.

Comment: @CodeGodie Thanks for your suggestion. I can understand that If I print it then it will display key. Nino Škopac gave me nice answer.

Comment: @LemonKazi awesome.. yea I was a bit thrown off initially. Glad you were able to understand.

Comment: This is the  ONLY way I found to do it - using eval: 
function    create_keyless_array($array_in,$key)
{

$str='';

foreach($array_in as $r)
  {
  if($str) $str.=',"'.$r[$key].'"'; else $str='array("'.$r[$key].'"';
  }

if($str)
  {
  $str .=')'; echo $str; //exit;
  eval('$simple_array='.$str.';');
  }
else
  $simple_array=array();

return $simple_array;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (which is available as of PHP 5.5):

```
$productIds = array_column($myList, 'product_id');
```

This gives you:

```
var_export($productIds);

array (
  0 => 8085,
  1 => 8087,
  2 => 8086,
  3 => 8042,
)
```

Which is exactly what you want:

```
var_dump($productIds === array(8085,8087,8086,8042)); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Plz note the right PHP Version for your answer! thnx

Comment: Yes this answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` function will output the keys. even if you use `array_values` the array still have indexes as keys.

Just output the the array manually using `echo` and `implode` (implode will join array values into a single string using the first parameter character):

```
echo implode(',', $newList);
```

Comment: I dont think he wants the string. I believe he has the correct result already. It seems that hes confused about the keys shown when using `print_r`

Comment: @CodeGodie maybe, his question was `display without key`, so I guess he wanted to display it, unless he will correct his question.

Comment: @RonDadon sorry if I put any mistake in my question. I just wanted array but implode will make it string.

Comment: LemonKazi so has @CodeGodie said, you already have that array, there is nothing you should do

Comment: Yes but if that display like it array (0=> then it was good. Like Nino Škopac answer has. He got my point. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays will always have keys. If you want an array, you can get all the values, turn them into one comma separated string, and place that into an array:

```
$productIds = [implode(',', array_column($myList, 'product_id'))];
var_dump($productIds);

// RESULT:
// array (size=1)
//   0 => string '8085,8087,8086,8042' (length=19)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me right way.